# should I access(create/show) many different tables in same api controller or different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, methods, controller

I am semi new to Rails and very new to making a Rails API. Currently, I am working on a semi large project with a bunch of different tables.

My question is, should I be creating a new controller for each table to create and show the information from each one? Or should I create one controller with one create and one show method that accesses all of the tables in the methods?